# Laravel send multiple HTTP responses

Tags: laravel, post, httpresponse

I created a small PHP API using Laravel in order to handle the communication with a biometric device.

I call the API using a POST request and I was wondering if it is possible to respond multiple times to only one POST?

For example: for enrollment, I call my API, the API launches enrollment on the device, and each time the device asks for a new finger I would like to send an update before the final response.

Comment: It feels like a job for sockets

Comment: you can use MQTT to achieve this you just only need to publish the response to the device on the given topic and the device will need to subscribe to that topic

Comment: Hi, thank you! So I tried using websockets with https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet

In the onMessage method I make my enrollment and every step I try to send a message. 
The problem is that it waits for the end of the enrollment and I receive everything at the same time on my front.